# Return XML response from lambda function(.Net Core)

Tags: .net, xml, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I have a lambda function in AWS written in .Net Core. Once it is called, it does sth and hopefully, it should return an xml string. However, the content type for return is still json. In API-Gateway->Integration Response->Mapping Templates->Content-type, I put application/xml.

The return should be like this:

```
<ANSWER>
<STATUS>0</STATUS>
</ANSWER>
```

But I get this actually:

```
"<ANSWER><STATUS>0</STATUS></ANSWER>"
```

double quotes and new-line apparently is not correct in this returned string.

I also have to mention that for returning this xml, I create a string like this:

```
string result = "<ANSWER><STATUS>0</STATUS></ANSWER>";
```

And at the end of lambda function I return this string like this:

```
return result;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway is set up to respond with a `Content-Type` of `application/json` instead of `application/xml`.

In your API Gateway method, click on the *Integration Response* link. Expand the `200` response and expand *Body Mapping Templates*. Remove the default `application/json` entry. Click *Add mapping template* and add `application/xml` with this mapping:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')) 
$inputRoot
```

This will convert the JSON string value to its plain contents.